# Get results from Laravel by putting the results from the query into another query in foreach

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I want to get results from Laravel by putting the results from the query into another query in foreach.

```
$first = DB::connection('store')
->table('entire_store')
->select('name', 'code', 'category', 'direct')
->where('open', 'Y')
->get();
```

The first query takes the information of the points and processes them into an array.

Match the information of the branches with the workplace in the employee table.

I want to save the workplace information of the employees together.

```
$temp = array();    
$i =0;    
foreach($first as $key => $item){

    $temp[$i]['name'] = $item->name;
    $temp[$i]['code'] = $item->code;

    $temp[$i]['category'] = $item->category;
    $temp[$i]['direct'] = $item→direct;

    $second = DB::connection('store')
     ->table('entire_employer')
     ->SELECT('mgr_no','mgr_id', 'status')
     ->where('store',$item->code)->get();
    //I tried.
    foreach($second as $key2 => $item2){
        $temp[$i]['mgr_id'] = $item2->mgr_id;
    }
    $i++;

}
```

I want to store the values from this query in temp_array.

I get an error if I try to save the value of the second query and print the value of temp_array ().

Is there anything more I need to do to check temp_array ()?

Comment: *I get an error if I try to save the value of the second query*, what was the error? perhaps it will shed more lights.. i do wonder why not going into `eloquent`..

Comment: Laravel prints only 500 errors. $ second I can see the value of temp_array when I print out the query, so I think the cause is on $ second query.

Comment: could you check that you are in debug mode so that the stacktrace printed into the html output? also its kind of hard to tell if the cause is the sql query unless we see your table structure for the involved tables..

Comment: Yes, but in this case I have to check the value first through dd ().

Comment: The reason I think the query part is the problem is that if that part is omitted from the code, it can check the value stored in temp_array () through dd ().

Comment: hmmm, what was the error? i do wonder how the `where` will behave on that `$second` query. i havent tried, but if i remember correctly you had to use at least three parameters if you specify the value. can check on the [docs](https://laravel.com/api/5.6/Illuminate/Database/Query/Builder.html#method_where). try to change `->where('store',$item->code)` to `->where('store', '=',$item->code)` first.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you are trying to do is a **LEFT JOIN** of the `entire_employer` table onto the `entire_store` table. That will do exactly what you're trying to do in your code: match the records of one table with the records on the other; a **LEFT** join will anchor those records in the primary table (`entire_store`, in this case).

You can do this in a single query, as such:

```
$data = DB::connection('store')
  ->table('entire_store')
  ->select(
      'entire_store.name', 
      'entire_store.code', 
      'entire_store.category', 
      'entire_store.direct', 
      'entire_employer.mgr_no', 
      'entire_employer.mgr_id', 
      'entire_employer.status'
  )
  ->leftJoin('entire_employer', 'entire_employer.store', '=', 'entire_store.id')
  ->where('entire_employer.open', 'Y')
  ->get();
```

You can read more about joins here: https://www.sitepoint.com/understanding-sql-joins-mysql-database/